# PromQL avg() on a range vector

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics, metricsql

What is the meaning of applying avg() over a range vector such as:

```
avg(meric_name[1d])
```

As per the documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators), it only operated on an instant vector. The metric_name[1d] returns a range vector. This query still runs over the range vector and returns a result without any complains about being wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The `avg(m[d])` query doesn't work in Prometheus as Brian already noted, because this is valid [MetricsQL](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html) query and is invalid PromQL query.

VictoriaMetrics automatically converts the `avg(m[d])` query to `avg(last_over_time(m[d]))`. The `last_over_time(m[d])` returns the last raw values for `m` over `d` duration for every returned data point. Then the `avg(...)` calculates average for resulting time series.

The `last_over_time()` function could be useful for covering gaps in time series data if these gaps exceed `step` value passed to [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries).

See more details about `last_over_time()` function at [MetricsQL docs](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html).

Answer (score 0):

This correctly returns a parse error:

```
Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:5: parse error: expected type instant vector in aggregation expression, got range vector
```

which you can see yourself at http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.expr=avg(meric_name%5B1d%5D)%20&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h

So I suspect you were running a different query.

Comment: thanks, was doing this against victoriaMetrics which did not complain